# Woocommerce / Remove "Payment Instructions" from Completed Orders ONLY

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have spent the last 2 hours reading posts about this, trying different lines of code, but none of them do exactly what I'd like to do.

As the headline says, I'd like to remove the PAYMENT INSTRUCTIONS from my Woocommerce emails, but ONLY for the Completed Emails orders, and also for both Payment Methods > Cash on Delivery and Bank Transfer !

I have tried this code found in a post here. Unfortunately it does not work.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'action_email_before_order_table_callback', 9, 4 );

function action_email_before_order_table_callback( 
 $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email 
){
    $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method();

// Targeting "COD" payment method on Customer completed order email notification
    if ( 'customer_completed_order' === $email->id && 'cod' === $payment_method ) {
        $available_gateways = WC()->payment_gateways->get_available_payment_gateways();
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', [ $available_gateways[$payment_method], 'email_instructions' ], 10 );
     }
}
```

And I have also tried this one, which works, but for ALL EMAILS.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', function() {
    if( function_exists( 'wc_gateway_remove_hook' ) ) {
        wc_gateway_remove_hook( 'WC_Gateway_COD', 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'email_instructions' );
    }
}, 10);

function wc_gateway_remove_hook( $classname, $hook, $callback ) {
    foreach( (array) $GLOBALS['woocommerce']->payment_gateways->payment_gateways as $key => $gateway_obj ) {
        if( $classname === get_class( $gateway_obj ) || 'customer_completed_order' === $email->id && 'cod' === $payment_method ) {
            remove_action( $hook, array( $gateway_obj, $callback ) );
        }
    }
}
```

I can sort of read through php, but I am no expert to modify it.
So any other code ideas are welcome ! Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for Cash on Delivery:

```
function wc_gateway_remove_hook( $classname, $hook, $callback ) {
    foreach( (array) $GLOBALS['woocommerce']->payment_gateways->payment_gateways as $key => $gateway_obj ) {
        if( $classname === get_class( $gateway_obj ) || 'customer_completed_order' === $email->id && 'cod' === $payment_method ) {
            remove_action( $hook, array( $gateway_obj, $callback ) );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'remove_instr_email_before_order_table_callback', 9, 4 );
function remove_instr_email_before_order_table_callback( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method();
    if ( 'customer_completed_order' === $email->id && 'cod' === $payment_method ) {
        if( function_exists( 'wc_gateway_remove_hook' ) ) {
            wc_gateway_remove_hook( 'WC_Gateway_COD', 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'email_instructions' );
        }
    }
}
```